# Spring return custom message not returning as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got the following error classes:

```
private static class GenericError extends Error {
        private int code;
        private String message;
        private Date timestamp;

        public GenericError(String message, int code, String message1) {
            super(message);
            this.code = code;
            this.message = message1;
            this.timestamp = new Date();
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        @Override
        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public Date getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
    }
    private static class ConfirmResponse extends GenericError {
        private String confirmMessage;
        private String instructions;


        public ConfirmResponse(String message, int code, String message1, String confirmMessage, String instructions) {
            super(message, code, message1);
            this.confirmMessage = confirmMessage;
            this.instructions = instructions;
        }

        public String getConfirmMessage() {
            return confirmMessage;
        }

        public String getInstructions() {
            return instructions;
        }
    }
```

I'm using it like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="login", method=RequestMethod.POST,  produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    FbLoginResponse login(@RequestBody Body body) throws IOException, InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, ConfirmLogin, ClassNotFoundException, ConfirmResponse {
            
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 
            ... 

            ConfirmResponse r = new ConfirmResponse("Error", 111, "An account already exists under this email",
                    "Please confirm your account",
                    "Log in with your prev account");

            throw r;
```

But the response I'm getting is incorrect:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1467604509746,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.userapi.spring.controller.UserController$ConfirmResponse",
  "message": "An account already exists under this email",
  "path": "/user/login/fac

ebook"
}
```

I also tried extending ***Exception*** which produced the same message.

#### Edit

I want to be able to return multiple different ***Class objects*** to the client. So if there was an error I could return a

```
new Error("Error occured")
```

and if I needed to return a custom message I could do

```
return new CustomMessage("Check your Email!);
```

I cannot do this when I define the return type of the controller e.g

```
LoginResp login(@RequestBody UserFacebookLoginContext body)

... I can only return LoginResp, I cannot return ErrorResponse, or CustomResponse
```

Basically what I want to be able todo is return multiple types of classes e.g

```
 AnyResp login(@RequestBody UserFacebookLoginContext body)
 if error ... return new ErrorResponse("something went wrong");

 if requires-custom ... return new CustomResponse ("Please check your email");
```

Comment: uhm, is really necesary return in your function a object `FbLoginResponse ` ? instead of it, you can use `ResponseEntity<?>` and return your custom message inside the response entity

Comment: What makes it incorrect?

Comment: It's not printing the json @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: What JSON? And why do you expect that?

Comment: Spring serializes java objects to JSON right? You must be right, I've gotta somehow return a JSON obj or use ResponseEntity @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Because there are multiple places the controller can error, so It'd be good if I could return different objects

Comment: Another question: why is `GenericError` an `Error` and why are you throwing it?

Comment: I've updated my question @SotiriosDelimanolis - I added generic error so I can have a more detailed error to extend off!

Comment: you can return a JSON inside the ResponseEntity, but thinking a bit, if you get an internal error, it doesn't do its work

Comment: after reading your update, i can tell you that you can return differents type of object with ResponseEntity, but as i said, if is an internal error, would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll leave you an example of how i handle diffent objects to return with `ResponseEntity`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {
    List<Transferencia> list = transferenciaDAO.getAll();
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {//here you can return any type of object doing your respective control of field.
        JsonResponse msj = new JsonResponse("Error", "List empty");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msj, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

also if you don't want to return any error. you can just return something similar to this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Comment: Doing this returns a long stack trace in the response object...Any way to leave this out?!

Comment: you can just return the `HttpsStatus` it will return a blank response